# Tag name autocompletion shouldn't touch tags with ending * wildcard

Tags: feature-request, tags, autocomplete

I add tag patterns to the list of ignored tags often, like "foo*".  Tag name autocompletion, while certainly being a useful feature, makes *this particular* task more difficult.  Basically, whenever I hit Tab key, "foo*" is replaced with "foo" (or something else), because "foo*" is not in the list.  In effect, I have to hit Esc to close autocompletion list and only then Tab, to move focus to the "Add" button.  This is made more difficult by the fact that the list doesn't appear instantly.

Request: please somehow disable autocompletion if currently entered tag name ends with '*'.  Or at least "default" autocompletion, i.e. if I didn't interact with the list in any way other than just hitting Tab.